# How to show only icon to the particular user when we click on it using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to show icon when it is hovered and clicked on the particular User but here when i click on the icon of particular user then i could see for the other users also showing the icon without hovering or clicking on it. Can anyone help me in this query?

Here is code:

```
<Card>
        {Data.map(user => (
          <CardHeader
            key={user.id}
            className={classes.header}
            avatar={<Avatar aria-label="recipe">R</Avatar>}
            action={
              <div className={this.state.menu && classes.menu}>
                <IconButton
                  id="simple-menu"
                  className={classes.showIcon}
                  aria-label="settings"
                  aria-controls="simple-menu"
                  onClick={this.handleClick}
                >
                  <MoreVertIcon />
                </IconButton>
                <Menu
                  style={{ marginTop: "35px" }}
                  id="simple-menu"
                  keepMounted
                  anchorEl={this.state.menu}
                  open={Boolean(this.state.menu)}
                  onClose={this.handleClose}
                >
                  <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>View</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>hide</MenuItem>
                </Menu>
              </div>
            }
            title={user.title}
            subheader={user.subheader}
          />
        ))}
      </Card>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-menu-button-visibility-fix-hujx4

For ex: if i click on `Shrimp and Chorizo Paella` User (dot icon) then we could see same icon visible in the other user `Sherlock holmes`. My objective is to show the icon whenever i hover the user card, and when we click on the icon, then the icon should visible only on the respective user card but not in other User card

Comment: Could you create codesandbox reproducing your issue? Which would help you to get faster solution..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan - Sure, I've updated in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the same state for all of your cards. You are deciding on 
the basis of `state.menu` for all cards resulting in the same behaviour no matter on which card the event has occured. As a result if the `state.menu` is set to value by hovering on any card & the menu of all the cards is visible. To solve this you will need to uniquely identify your card. For that you will need to manage state for each card. You can achieve it like this:

- Create a state for each card identified by `user.id` using the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook before return the `<Card>` component.

```js
let cardStates = {}
Data.map(user => {
  cardStates[user.id] = { menu: null }
});
this.setState(cardStates);
...
```

- Convert your handle events to callbacks

```js
<Menu
  style={{ marginTop: "35px" }}
  id="simple-menu"
  keepMounted
  anchorEl={this.state[user.id].menu}
  open={Boolean(this.state[user.id].menu)}
  onClose={this.handleClose}
>
  <MenuItem
    onClick={e => {
      this.handleClose(e, user.id);
    }}
  >
    View
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem
    onClick={() => {
      this.handleClose(user.id);
    }}
  >
    hide
  </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

- Manipulate state in handlers by accepting your `user.id` as argument.

```js
handleClick = (e, uid) => {
  let newCardState = {}
  newCardState[uid] = { menu: e.target }
  this.setState(newCardState);
};

handleClose = (uid) => {
  let newCardState = {}
  newCardState[uid] = { menu: null}
  this.setState(newCardState);
};
```